# Something changes DPMS settings

Tags: x11, dpms

I want my LCD-display to turn off after some time. Not display black image. Displaying black image is pointless because it drains a few Watts more than white image.

To do this I'm launching

```
  xset dpms 0 0 900
```

After some time this settings is lost. I know it happens when I disconnect the charger.

How can I find the program that changes DPMS settings?

Answer (score 0):

I have find it using

```
xlsclients -l
```

Just looked at all clients and guessed that xfce4-power-manager can change display configuration. I launched xfce4-power-manager-settings and disabled all DPMS stuff.

If something else is going to chenge DPMS I'll watching:

```
 while true; do xset q | grep -q Standby:.0 || xmessage "DPMS changed" ; sleep 5; done
```